# Associative table many on many with varying level of entity specificity

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, entity-relationship

I have the need to associate a message or a group of messages with a display or a group of displays.

A message has a type, and a display has a type and a location ( for example, a city)

I would like to associate a message or all messages of a certain type to a display or all display of a certain type and/or location.

My first idea was to build an associative table many on many, with the foreign keys:

- Message_id
- Message_type_id
- Display_id
- Display_location_id
- Display_type_id

And when adding an entry, set a value for the fields i am interested in ( for example message_type and display_location), and null to the others.

However, i was interested in the downsides of this approach, and wondering if there are better methods to handle this kind of problems. After some days searching (in vain) for this kind of pattern when designing a database, i ultimately decided to ask here.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach is sound.
It occurs to me that you only need Message_id  and Display_id  in the "intersection entity", as the other columns would probably come from the "parent" entity.

Message_type_id

Display_location_id
Display_type_id

Comment: I see, thanks. Is this a common approach when building associations between groups of entities with varying grouping criterias? is there a specific topic where i could learn more about the argument?

Comment: This is basic Relational DB Design.  I've been doing this since 1985, and I learned many years ago, so I'm afraid my sources would be too old.  I'm sure Google will help.